# Flask - Unable to run tests from tests folder (cannot perform relative import)

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

Hi i have the following project structure

- project

  - app/

    - **init**.py
    - views.py
    - forms.py
    - models.py
    - static/
    - templates/
  - config.py
  - project_database.db
  - requirements.txt
  - run.py
  - tests/

    - test_project.py

run.py

```
from app import app 
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask                                                                 
from playhouse.flask_utils import FlaskDB

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')

flask_db = FlaskDB(app)

database = flask_db.database

from app import views
```

tests/test_project.py

```
from ..app import app
import unittest

class TestProject(unittest.TestCase):
       ''' tests'''
```

When i try to run my tests i get the following error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tests/test_status_code.py", line 1, in <module>
> from ..app import app SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
> ```

If i move the tests file out of the folder it runs but i'd like to have it in the folder so I can have all test files in there.

I am using python 3.5 anf Flask 0.12.2

Thanks

Comment: Cab you try to rename your init.py to __init__.py

Comment: My init.py already has the double underscores its just when I posted the question it got removed.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this working by doing the following

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from app import app
import unittest

Class TestProject(unittest.TestCase):
```

But just cause this works is this right or is there a better more pythonic way?